# I can't recognise the 八 radical in many characters

Tags: radicals

I have my oxford and tuttle dictionary in front of me and the radical list has a lot of characters with 八 as it's radical, which means "divide" apparently.

But where is this radical in 兰 ，半 ，弟， 单 etc ?

Is it written in mirror in those characters? Thank you

Comment: What helped me was to download a list of radicals for Anki. The list included the radical in its bare form, and also in some of its variants. That helped me to remember. But actually, I'm not sure it helped me much to memorize the really, really small parts of radicals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

丷 is a variant of 八, just as 灬 is a variant of 火.

Variant characters are common for radicals, given that they can occur at difference positions within a composite character.